# Include html verification file in root Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to place a html file in the root directory of the built and deployed files. It's a verification file for a 3rd party service that requires a `<example-key>.html` file in the root.

I'm using `npm run build` (vue-cli) when preparing the files (the dist folder) which I deploy with `firebase deploy`.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Could you share more info on your configuration (incl. firebase.json)? Can't you add this file in the folder that you deploy with the CLI together with the vue.js dist folder and index.html file?

Comment: I've tried to include it in the dist folder without luck.

Comment: What URL do you want assign to this file? `https://yourprojectid.firebaseapp.com/example-key.html` ??

Answer (score 0):

You normally put the content of your vue.js `dist` folder (generated through `npm run build`) into the `public` folder of Firebase hosting (and overwwrite the default `index.html` file initially generated by the Firebase project setup script).

Then in you `firebase.json` file you have the following `rewrite` in order to handle the Single Page Application behavior of you vue.js application (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites))

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    ...
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you add your `example-key.html` file at the same level than the `index.html` file generated by the vue-cli you should be able to open it via:

```
https://yourprojectid.firebaseapp.com/example-key.html
```